# Uwsgi/Nginx Gives Me -- unavailable modifier requested: 0 -- Error

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to get uwsgi to work with nginx on a Gentoo System. Here's how I have it configured:

```
nginx:

    server {
        listen 192.168.1.40;
        server_name localhost;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log info;

    location ~* (web|download|authenticate|db_login|delete|dir_list|upload)\.py$ {
                uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
                include uwsgi_params;
        }


        root /var/www/dude;
    }

development uwsgi.d # cat web.ini 
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
chdir = /home/one/development/copy_files/modules/
module = web
processes = 4
threads = 2
development uwsgi.d #
```

I have a simple python script to test:
    development uwsgi.d #  cat /home/one/development/copy_files/modules/web.py

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return "Hello World"
development uwsgi.d #
```

The way I call the script is in javascript with:

```
xml.open("GET", "python/web.py", true);
```

But when I click on the button of my web page that runs `xml.open("GET", "python/web.py", true);` I get a "-- unavailable modifier requested: 0 --" uwsgi error:

```
development uwsgi.d # uwsgi web.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from web.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 1.4.10 (64bit) on [Tue Sep 17 19:59:07 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 17 September 2013 19:12:48
os: Linux-3.10.7-gentoo #1 SMP Wed Sep 11 20:17:44 CDT 2013
nodename: development
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi.d
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 16003
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:3031 fd 3
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
mapped 329536 bytes (321 KB) for 8 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 27975, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 27976, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 27977, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 27978, cores: 2)
-- unavailable modifier requested: 0 --
-- unavailable modifier requested: 0 --
-- unavailable modifier requested: 0 --
```

Comment: Note: Found the answer...I had to use /usr/bin/uwsgi_python27 instead of just uwsgi.

Answer (score 1):

gentoo packages are modular, you need to load the uWSGI python plugin